# Why does the function toTitleCase not work with the english(1), but toupper does?

Tags: r, class, typeof

I'm using the `library(english)` to get my rmarkdown doc correct with APA guidelines on when to write out numbers as words. Super handy, I can just wrap my values in `english()` and they come out correct.

Obviously, when starting a sentence with a number it needs the first letter capitalized, so I'd thought I could just wrap `english(1)` in `tools::toTitleCase()`, but it doesn't like it:

```
Error in toTitleCase(english(1)) : 'text' must be a character vector
```

`toupper(english(1))` works just as one might expect:

```
> toupper(english(1))
[1] "ONE"`
```

I have a working solution:

`toTitleCase(as.character(english(1)))`

Fine by me but...

...what's going on here? Why is `toupper()` able to deal with the output of `english(1)` as you'd expect, but `toTitleCase()` throws the error?

Reprex:

```
install.packages("english")
library(engilsh)
library(tools)

toTitleCase(english(1))

toupper(english(1))
```

EDIT:

I'm an idiot: there's the function `english::Words(1)`, which does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I suspect, `english()` returns an object of class `english` rather than `character`. `toTitkeCase` requires a character input. But I’m not going to install the package to confirm. What dies `class(english(1))` give you?

Comment: yup, quite right, see the answer of @benson23 below.

Comment: We posted simmultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you play around with the output of `english(1)`, you will find that it has a class of "english" and having a type of "double", which is obviously not "character".

```r
library(english)

class(english(1))
[1] "english"

typeof(english(1))
[1] "double"
```

And in the source code of `toupper()`, you can find that there is a statement to test whether your input is of type "character", if not, it will coerce it for you:

```
toupper
function (x) 
{
    if (!is.character(x)) 
        x <- as.character(x)
    .Internal(toupper(x))
}
```

On the other hand, `toTitleCase()` will just throw an error if the input is not "character":

```
toTitleCase ### only the relevant part is extracted below
function (text) 
{
  ###
  if (typeof(text) != "character") 
    stop("'text' must be a character vector")
}
```

Therefore, `toupper` can innately handle non-character input but `toTitleCase` cannot.

Comment: So is it correct that  `toTitleCase(as.character(something))` will work, or does it take more work to convert class "english" to class "character" ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes - that does work, as in my original question.

Comment: Thanks @benson23! Do you know why a function would want to create it's own class, rather than just setting the output type to character?

Comment: @gladys_c_hugh it's not "creating" a class. It only wants character type input. You attempted to give it a Boolean type.

Comment: "why would a function want to create its own class?": so that it plays nicely with related functions.  In this case, other functions in the `english` package.